# Saving tweets in MySql throws "Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xB2\xF0\x9F"

Tags: mysql

I am trying to save tweets into MySql db, most of the time it works fine, but when tweet's like the ones given below come,

[Example 1](https://twitter.com/MishaDaily/status/36940160026925056)
[Example 2](http://twitter.com/alexisgrylls/status/369417236894584833)

I get the following exception from MySql,

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x92\xB2\xF0\x9F...' for column 'twtText' at row 1
```

How can we handle such texts.

Comment: So, how did you solve this in the end?

Comment: Also getting this error in phpMyAdmin, Maria DB 10.1. Column and table are set to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`, not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. Changing the character set in MySql

```
ALTER TABLE TableName MODIFY COLUMN ColumnName varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Comment: dont use 255 for uft8mb, it uses 4 byets per char, not 3.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your column's charset to the value reflecting the charset of the strings you want to insert.

Example:

```
ALTER TABLE database.table MODIFY COLUMN col VARCHAR(255)  CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting the collation on the database table / column, we also had to set on the client, in the app, the collation with:
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';

before the actual statement .
Similar errors: [Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xB6\xF0\x9F...' MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issure and solveld it.
The cause of the error is that the string contains emoticons.

1. set your mysql column's charset to `utf8mb4` and Collation to `utf8mb4_general_ci`
2. set your connection string of charset to `utf8mb4` like `charset=utf8mb4`
3. ok, test it