# "Incorrect string value:" Java & MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, utf8mb4

I am working with some Twitter text and when trying to write to a database I get the following error:

Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x96\xF0\x9F...'

I read that that the text field should be set to uft8mb4 and I've done that, but still getting the error.  Any ideas on what could be going on?

Comment: Thanks for the reply and it makes sense, but isn't that what I've essentially done here:  http://i.imgur.com/zUeUYO0.jpg

Comment: Have you tried this to make sure the changes are made: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20429481/1913389?

Comment: I ran the following (still not working):

SET NAMES utf8mb4; 
ALTER DATABASE tweet_schema CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;