# MySQl - incorrect string value on version from latin1 to utf8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, type-conversion, latin1, utf8mb4

So we originally had latin1 for our MySQL database (a long long time ago) and we are trying to convert to UTF8 before a more global outreach, but I'm having issues with the transition. Here's my MySQL:

```
/* First set as latin1 */
SET NAMES 'latin1';

/* We must change things to blob and then back again */
ALTER TABLE `address` CHANGE line_1 line_1 BLOB;
ALTER TABLE `address` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE `address` CHANGE line_1 line_1 VARCHAR(64);
```

And the error we are getting:

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF6gberg...' for column 'line_1' at row 7578
ALTER TABLE `address` CHANGE line_1 line_1 VARCHAR(64)
```

The method we are using is basically described through here:
http://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/16/utf8-data-on-latin1-tables-converting-to-utf8-without-downtime-or-double-encoding/
Any ideas would be great. (Also, since I'm not an expert in MySQL not sure what kind of data you would need, so lemme know if you need anything additional.)

**Update**

I've tried

```
SET NAMES 'utf8';
SET NAMES 'utf8mb4';
```

And I tried using utf8mb4 as was described below. After switching to utf8mb4 (which I'll likely keep), the alteration of of the address still produced the same problem.

**Update 2**
So I tried looking at converting the string itself to see what's happening and noticed something super weird:

```
mysql> select line_1 from address where line_1 like '%berg%';
+------------------------+
| line_1                 |
+------------------------+
| H�bergsgatan 97        |
+------------------------+

mysql> select CONVERT(line_1 USING utf8) from address where line_1 like '%berg%';
+----------------------------+
| CONVERT(line_1 USING utf8) |
+----------------------------+
| NULL                       |
+----------------------------+

mysql> select CONVERT(line_1 USING utf8mb4) from address where line_1 like '%berg%';
+-------------------------------+
| CONVERT(line_1 USING utf8mb4) |
+-------------------------------+
| NULL                          |
+-------------------------------+

mysql> select CONVERT(line_1 USING latin1) from address where line_1 like '%berg%';
+------------------------------+
| CONVERT(line_1 USING latin1) |
+------------------------------+
| Högbergsgatan 97             |
+------------------------------+
```

So it seems like utf isn't the proper encoding for this? o_O As I'm working with addresses I was able to look it up and it seems like the address is in Stockholm and is supposed to be "Högbergsgatan 97" which matches latin1. I tried the swedish character encoding, but that seems to have failed as well:

```
mysql> select CONVERT(line_1 USING swe7) from address where addressid = 11065;
+----------------------------+
| CONVERT(line_1 USING swe7) |
+----------------------------+
| H?gbergsgatan 97           |
+----------------------------+
```

So I'm trying to see what I can do to rectify this.

Also, note that I had forgotten earlier to state that I'm using MySQL 5.6 (if that makes any difference)

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql

Comment: unknown variable 'default-character-set=utf8' - I'm using MySQL 5.6 so changing the default char set won't work. Additionally, I tried SET NAMES 'utf8'; and that didn't work either. (Unless you are stating I should switch to utf8mb4?)

Comment: I also just tried utf8mb4 with no success (see my edit)

Comment: so, if you try to alter blob to utf8mb4 you encounter the same error?

Comment: Yeah. I tried with and without collating, both produce the same error... #superweird Also, I fixed the default-character-set thing, turns out I put it in the wrong spot (mysqld doesn't support it) after moving it 5.6 stopped complaining. So I do have the default-character-set, set to utf8mb4 as well now.