# Mysql JDBC Incorrect string value and "?" character encoding

Tags: java, mysql, character, utf8mb4

I have 2 problem at the same time which i solve them but when i fix one of them the other problem raise again, one of them is character encoding when i insert some sentence, db shows **Ş,İ,ş,ı** characters as a **"?"** i solved this problem putting the **useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=utf8**

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Wiki?useUnicode=yes&**characterEncoding=utf8**&&user=root&password=
```

But my second problem,

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x90\x8C\xB2\xF0\x90...' for column 'w_text' at row 1
```

When i remove the **characterEncoding=utf8** the problem is resolved but my first problem raise again.

By the way i change the db character group as **utf8mb4_general_ci**

Any idea for this?

Comment: Just to make sure, is your project encoded using utf-8?

Comment: No not encoded, just parsing some xml data.

Comment: Followed this question and solved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql