# Incorrect string value when trying to pass emoji to the db encoded with utf8mb4

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysql-8.0

I have a database with charset `utf8mb4` and collation `utf8mb4-bin`. The table and the column to which I'm inserting also have such properties. My PHP file is saved in UTF-8 (without BOM). My `$dsn` variable used for a PDO connection looks like this: `$dsn = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=vk_comments;port=3306;charset=utf8mb4;connect_timeout=15'`. I'm on PHP 7.2, by the way.

And yet MySQL keeps saying that it got `Incorrect string value`. As you can see, I set the proper charset everywhere. What else could be the issue?

### ADDITIONAL INFO

Example value before input: 
The exact error I'm getting from MySQL: `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect string value: \u0027\\xF0\\x9F\\x98\\x8A\u0027 for column \u0027comment_text\u0027 at row 1`

Comment: Please show value before input. Not db configurations. And what particular error do you getting back.

Comment: Please see the edit

Comment: Please code where you are inserting data into db. Whole code from input to insert into db. What sql syntax do you use and etc.

Comment: I'm inserting it like this: `$sql = "INSERT INTO level_1 (comment_id, user_id, user_name, user_photo, url, comment_text, comment_date) VALUES (:comment_id, :user_id, :user_name, :user_photo, :url, :comment_text, :comment_date)";
   $pdo->prepare($sql)->execute($data);`. The variable `comment_text` contains that emoji I specified in the question.

Comment: Similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql

Comment: maybe you need to set `SET = utf8mb4 COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci;`

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyB1988. I hadn't seen that one. I've read that using `set names` was a bad practice, but it's the only thing that helped. Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `$this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);`

I had to add

`$this->dbh->exec("set names utf8mb4");`

Only this one worked.