# Python 3 + Mysql: Incorrect string value '\xF0\x9F\x85\x97\xF0\x9F...'

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, character-encoding

I have found other questions/answers about "Incorrect string value" here on stack but none of the answers are working so maybe something is different about my case.

```
try:
    self.cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='emails', password='***',
                                               database='extractor', raise_on_warnings=True)
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("Something is wrong with your user name or password")
    elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("Database does not exist")
    else:
        print(err)
self.sql = self.cnx.cursor()

biography = str(row[8])
self.sql.execute("""insert into emails (biography)
                            values(%s)""",
                                         (biography,))
```

where `biography` is a `utf8mb4_general_ci` **TEXT** column of:

`< Living the   > Azofra & Clifford Travel Food Fashion`

I get:

```
mysql.connector.errors.DataError: 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x85\x97\xF0\x9F...' for column `extractor`.`emails`.`biography` at row 1
```

Output of `show create table emails`:

```
show create table emails;
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table  | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| emails | CREATE TABLE `emails` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ufeff_user_id` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `username` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `full_name` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_private` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `follower_count` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `following_count` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_count` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `biography` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `has_profile_pic` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `external_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `public_email` varchar(320) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `contact_phone_number` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `address_street` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_business` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `engagement` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `recent_post_date` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(75) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_likes` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_comments` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_join_date` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_count` int(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `business_ads` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_code` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `emailscol` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `city_name` varchar(75) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `email` (`public_email`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=139 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: `'< Living the   > Azofra & Clifford Travel Food Fashion'`

Comment: Let's see the connection parameters in python.

Comment: Question updated.

Answer (score 6):

I'm assuming the column `emails.biography` is of type `VARCHAR`, and that the `CHARSET` for the **table** `emails` is `utf8mb4`. If not, you'd want to execute:

```
 ALTER TABLE `emails` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;
```

Then, if that doesn't solve the issue, try executing the following directly after you create your MySQL cursor in Python (assuming `self.sql` is your cursor):

```
 self.sql.execute('SET NAMES utf8mb4;')
 self.sql.execute('SET CHARACTER SET utf8mb4;')
 self.sql.execute('SET character_set_connection=utf8mb4;')
```

And if that doesn't work, try setting the character set immediately after you create the MySQL connection in Python, for example:

```
 self.connection.set_character_set('utf8mb4')
```

If you're still out of luck at this point, we can debug further :)

**Update:**

Try:

```
ALTER TABLE `emails` CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
ALTER TABLE `emails` CHANGE COLUMN `biography` TEXT CHARACTER SET 'utf8';
```

Note that `utf8mb4_general_ci` is the collation of the table, not the encoding. Ideally, you should be using `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci`.

Comment: It is a uft8bm4 field already of type TEXT. Question updated.

Comment: `self.cnx.set_character_set('utf8mb4')` produces: `AttributeError: 'MySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'set_character_set'` so I had to do: `self.cnx.set_charset_collation('utf8bm4')` which produces: `Character set 'utf8bm4' unsupported.`. I also tried `utf8bm4_general_ci` with same result.

Comment: Try changing all `utf8mb4` to `utf8`. `utf8mb4` was introduced in MySQL version 5.5, so presumably you're using a rather old MySQL installation. Also, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Are you able to paste your `my.cnf`? You probably should update it if you haven't already. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429481/2178980. I could do it for you if you send me what you have currently.

Comment: Also, can you paste the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE emails;`?

Comment: @Eugene  `show create table emails` https://hastebin.com/nefemegugu.sql

Comment: @Eugene also it gives syntax error for the `CHANGE COLUMN` command.

Comment: I added the lines to `my.cnf` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/20429481/2178980 . Still getting the same error when I run my script.

Comment: You still have `utf8` stuff. Try this https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4#utf8-to-utf8mb4

Comment: Great! This saved my day. I have been trying to put Emojis into the MySQL using Python, but it didn't work. 
Second solution (of executing `SET names utf8mb4` and other queries) worked for me properly.

By the way, this should be accepted answer. I don't know why it isn't.