# Uncategorized SQL Exception while trying to save a name field

Tags: java, sql, database, sap-commerce-cloud

I am currently facing an issue while trying to set a name field in DB using Java. As the names comes from a third party vendor, we get special characters like musical notes or smileys in the name field (e.g.  )

Due to the above reason, the DB throws an exception below.
org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: query; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [HY000]; error code [1366]; Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x8E\xB6' for column 'name'

I want to filter out such characters before setting it in the field.

Please let me know how can I handle the above via regex before setting the values.

Comment: it may need encoding configurations on the server.

Comment: sanitize ... sanitize data

Comment: What about using double quotes, forcing a name? `";)"` And using UTF-8/32

Answer (score 0):

Before saving to database, you need to check and remove a special character from the name string.

This answer has a code to check and remove a special character.

[how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552253/how-to-remove-special-characters-from-a-string/7552284)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried setting charset as **utfmb4** as it supports special characters at db level?

This can be applied, if you intended to allow special characters, else you need to have a mechanism to remove special characters before saving it to database.

For more details, you can check below link

[Charset_in_mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql)