# How to change the default charset for in MySQL?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I have a python code which adds rows to the MySQL database which runs on the same machine. The code is as follows:

```py
import mysql.connector

config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'a$$enjoyer',
  'host': 'localhost',
  'database': 'db',
  'raise_on_warnings': True
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
con = cnx.cursor()
```

Now, I have a table which has a `MEDIUMTEXT` column. The issue is that whenever I try to insert texts with emojis (yes, I need them), I get the error like: `1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\xA5\xB6' for column 'epictext' at row 1`.

The code is as follows:

```py
con.execute('INSERT INTO nice VALUES(%s,%s,%s)', [1,2,''])
```

I have found a few questions here which addressed this error like, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20411440/incorrect-string-value-xf0-x9f-x8e-xb6-xf0-x9f-mysql) one, but they didn't fix the issue.

The weird thing is that simply running `INSERT INTO nice VALUES(1,2,'');` directly in MySql console works fine. Moreover adding the `'collation': 'utf8mb4_general_ci'` to `config` fixes the issue entirely, but when I last tried doing this, this line was not necessary, and I would really like to avoid using it if it is possible.

Comment: You could try to [set the encoding of the python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6289474/working-with-utf-8-encoding-in-python-source) to see if that works. Also lol at your db password

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify 'charset' and 'collation' like below in your config

```
config = {
  'user': 'root',
  'password': 'a$$enjoyer',
  'host': 'localhost',
  'database': 'db',
  'raise_on_warnings': True,
  'charset': 'utf8mb4',
  'collation': 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci'
}

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, but this is exactly what I have described in the question. I know that this is the solution. The question is rather how to make it so that I don't have to add this line.